# Этимология слова "лобогрейка"

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, история

Как произошло слово "лобогрейка"? Что оно значит и как связано со лбом?

Comment: Может быть, лобогрейка - это условно-образно?

Comment: @Инна а каким образом?

Answer (score 1):

Этимология прозрачная - сложение основ: лоб + греть.

[ЛОБОГРЕ́ЙКА](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-encycl-term-31455.htm) (с.-х.). Жнейка простой конструкции, без прибора для сбрасывания сжатого хлеба.

> Лобогрейка, знаете, почему называется? Потому что очень быстро лошадки
>   ходят и механизмы работают, надо очень быстро бросать снопы, и лоб
>   мокрый всё время, лобогрейка называлась, то есть потеет человек
>   сильно. Вымолачивали зерно (Толст. Тамб.).

**[источник](http://file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B/Downloads/slovar.pdf)**

---

> Лобогрейка производит срезание стеблей убираемой культуры и
>   укладывание их на платформу. Сбрасывание срезанного хлеба с платформы
>   производится вручную, что требует большого физического напряжения от
>   рабочего, выполняющего эту операцию, и отчего машина получила своё
>   название — «лобогрейка».

**[источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0)**

Comment: Недостоверно. Почему именно лоб? От работы потеет прежде всего спина.

Comment: Ну, что сложение основ (правда, если уж этимология *совсем* прозрачная, просто необходимо добавить, что с соединительным гласным *-о-*), это понятно. А вот со лбом — непрозрачно.

Comment: Отзываюсь на недостоверный и непрозрачный лоб: во-первых, у кого что потеет - это индивидуально, во-вторых, спина прикрыта рубашкой (футболкой, майкой), которая и впитывает пот, а вот лоб - открыт, на него набегают капли, которые и стряхивают изячным движением, скопированным у Миронова в "Бриллиантовой руке".

Comment: Почему ж недостоверно, очень даже достоверно, просто далеко от нашего понимания, а вот я про тружеников тыла очерки пишу, так все бабушки как одна вспоминают о лобогрейках, как в войну им приходилось на них работать, одна так и сказала: "Вот тогда я и поняла, почему она так называется: лоб горячий, пОтом глаза заливает, трава ко лбу прилипает, больше двух часов не выдержать, падали просто". Так что мотивационные отношения объясняются через привлечение энциклопедических сведений, данных народной этимологии, как и коновал - коней валит, а кто не знает, пусть в энциклопедию посмотрит.

Comment: Люсенька, спасибо за поддержку! ))) Я добавлю к теме "этимология": душегрейка, лобогрейка, водогрейка, телогрейка, носогрейка, - что, надо отдельно этимологию "грейки", чтоб уж всё проговорить? О_о

Comment: @Людмила *Почему ж недостоверно, очень даже достоверно,* - недостоверно образование от горячего лба. Аналогов нет. "Горячий лоб" - это про другое. А бабушка даёт обычное в таких случаях "народное" объяснение.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova *душегрейка, лобогрейка, водогрейка, телогрейка, носогрейка* - вот потому и недостоверно, что в этот ряд не ложится. Здесь греется именно та часть тела, о которой речь. А лоб как показатель того, что человек согрелся или вспотел -  совершенно нехарактерно.

Comment: Зря Вы так думаете, поговорите с теми, кто на них работал. Я не работала, но помню, как студентами на зерне работали, так тоже лоб горячий был.

Answer (score 1):

А вам не кажется, что название произошло от слов "лоб" и "огреть"? Части одного из видов этого агрегата - вращающиеся лопасти-грабли - пролетают не так далеко от головы "оператора". И если немного наклониться, то можно получить по лбу. Кстати, работа этого единственного "оператора" заключалась в управлении лошадью и вряд ли была настолько изматывающей, чтобы на лбу появлялась испарина.
А потом название перешло на другие виды механизированных жаток/жнеек.

Дополнение (исправлено):
Слово появляется с появлением предмета. То, что Вы называете жатка-самосброска, а я - лобогрейка, появилось в России в начале 1900-х гг или раньше, в XIX в. Есть открытка 1910 г - такая жатка (производства компании МакКормик) запряжена двумя верблюдами.
Только что спросил у 80-летнего человека. В 10-летнем возрасте он видел работу конкретно такой машины. И у них она называлась лобогрейка.
Поэтому я уверен, когда появилась жатка-самосброска, русский народ её с юмором метко назвал лобогрейка (от "лоб" и "огреть"). А потом на остальные механизмы (и со вторым сиденьем, и других конструкций) перешло как родовое слово.

В ответ.
Ну, да. Но лобоогрейка - ходульное слово, и "внутренняя" приставка сразу выпала за ненадобностью.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Лопасти-грабли были на жатках-самосбросках, там действительно - только одно сидение. На лобогрейке их два. Посмотрите в моем ответе "Жатвенные машины" и дополнение.

Comment: Тогда, следуя Вашим рассуждениям и правилам словообразования, название агрегата будет таким: ЛОБ-О-О-ГРЕ-Й-К-А.

Answer (score 0):

**лобогрейка**
Простейшая жатвенная машина с ручным сбрасыванием сжатого хлеба.
*Словарь русского языка в четырех томах, томII, 1958.*

**Жатвенные машины, жатки, жнеи, жнейки**
Так называются механизмы, служащие для уборки с поля **трав** ( клевера, тимофеевки и т. п. ), **хлебов** ( рожь, пшеница, овес и т. п. ), принадлежащих к семейству злаков, **масличных растений** ( рыжик, рапс, и проч. ), уборка которых производится ***срезанием.***

*Жатвенные машины были в употреблении еще в древности: их описание можно найти у Плиния и Палладия.*
 Но жнеи древности не похожи на нынешние. По описанию Палладия, жнея, употреблявшаяся в Галлии, состояла из четырехугольного ящика, на одном краю которого была гребенка с зубцами, наклоненными от ящика, который устанавливался на оси с двумя колесами; от него шли две оглобли, в коих запрягали вола; вол, впряженный посредством хомута сзади ящика, двигал жнею. Колосья хлеба попадали между зубьями гребенки, срывались ею и падали в ящик, а солома оставалась на меже...
 Машина, служившая в Галлии для сжинания хлеба у римлян, уже не встречается, она исчезла безвозвратно...
[жатвенные машины](http://www.wikiznanie.ru/wikipedia/index.php/%D0%96%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B,_%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8,_%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8,_%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8)

**Я — жатка**. Еду по полю за трактором, своими зубьями, как гребешком, стебли расчёсываю и острыми ножами рожь или пшеницу скашиваю. Совсем как машинка для стрижки волос. Вертушка-мотовило укладывает колосья на мою деревянную площадку. А рабочий, который на этой площадке стоит, вилами или граблями их на землю сбрасывает.
**Нелегко ему приходится, пОтом бедняга обливается. Недаром прозвали меня лобогрейка!**
[лобогрейка](http://www.what-who.com/zh/zhatka.html)

**Лобогрейки** изготовлялись на заводах «Красный Аксай» (в Ростове-на-Дону) и на заводе в Херсоне.
Ширина захвата лобогрейки 1,56 м. Для привода лобогрейки в движение требуется 2-3 лошади. Потери зерновых при уборке лобогрейкой достигали 20-30 %.

***В настоящее время*** для скашивания и обмолота зерновых культур, выделения зерна, его очистки и сбора в бункер, сбора соломы и половы в копнитель или сброса их в поле ***применяются зерноуборочные комбайны.***
[Жатвенные машины](http://honeygarden.ru/garden/agricultural_machinery_equipment/37.php)

**Дополнение**
Возможно, рассказ того, кто работал на лобогрейке, и историческое исследование помогут понять "почему этот агрегат ТАК называется?":

Лобогрейка — ... производит только срезание стеблей убираемой культуры и укладывает их на платформу.
Сбрасывание же срезанного хлеба с платформы производится вручную, ***что
требует большого физического напряжения от рабочего, выполняющего эту
операцию, и отчего машина получила своѐ название «лобогрейка» (второе
сидение).***
*Первое сидение для управления лошадьми.* Обычно в них запрягают две лошади, но в наше время впереди коренного ставили еще одну лошадь, на которую садили подростка немного старше меня. Он создавал направление движения всего агрегата.
[Моя малая родина Маулень](http://www.vetinst.narod.ru/book/maulen.pdf)

... распространенным тогда средством механизации была *жатка-лобогрейка, из названия которой становится понятным, почему **даже крепкие мужчины не выдерживали работы на ней более двух часов подряд.***
Дело в том, что природа в нашем климате на уборку зерновых отпускает максимум две недели – от начала пожелтения растений до начала осыпания зерна из колосьев. Времени катастрофически не хватает. ***И самое тяжелое в жатве –*** **сжать *хлеб в валки*,** а уж подборку валков в снопы и установку снопов в копны – работа не такая спешная и ее делают и женщины с подростками. А далее – обмолот, провеивание и сушка зерна уже может производиться в спокойном темпе хоть до весны.
[История России](http://communitarian.ru/publikacii/istoriya_rossii/vinit_sovetskuyu_vlast_v_golodomore_nevozmozhno_29112014/)

Получается, что *глобальную* физическую нагрузку испытывал тот, кто работал на "втором сидении" (не более двух часов ), да еще и в жару.
Возможно, имелся в виду перегрев, тепловой удар, ведь обычно по лбу мы измеряем температуру. Наступал критический момент "лобогрева", и работник на втором сидении жатки менялся на "свежего".

Comment: Все интересно, но где этимология? Почему именно "лоб" и "грейка"?

Comment: Да, ответа на основной вопрос, к сожалению, здесь нет.

Answer (score 0):

Я выскажу версию далекую от достоверной, но другой нет. Ссылок поэтому точно не будет.

"Лоб", возможно, здесь в значении "детина", "крупный, сильный человек". Именно таких обычно и ставили на жатку.